# How do I remove the default margins when printing (when "Page Setup" options don't work)

Tags: macos, printing, firefox

I'm trying to print a web page that I've created with a custom paper size of 4.5x10.25 inches. I want the page to be printed right to the edge of the paper, with no margins at all.

I've been reading for a few hours and the best thing I can find is to use Mac's Page Setup dialog to create a custom paper size and custom margins, which I've done and set to the default for all of my printers. (Hopefully I'm able to post links to images --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5xyt.png). No matter what I do though I can't get the margins to go away. There's always always always a .75 inch margin when I print and when I print preview (Again, hoping I can post links to images --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Mqh.png).

Things I've tried:

- I've read that the margins are only visible in print preview and printing the page will remove them. This didn't work.
- I've tried tricking the system by setting my margins to 0.01 inches
- I've tried adjusting the website to not be exactly the size of the page (I made it smaller) and the margins were still there.
- I've set "print.print_extra_margin" to 0 in Firefox's about:config page.
- I've tried a different printer.
- I've tried a co-worker's machine running a newer version of OSX.
- I've made absolutely sure that my page size it set correctly.

I'm using OSX 10.6.8 with Firefox v21.0.

The closest I can come to this is using Google Chrome, where there is a specific option for "none" in margins and the Chrome preview looks okay, but I'm not able to specify paper size unless I click "Print using system dialog" which gives me the same problems as above.

How do I remove the margins and just fit to the exact size of the page?

Comment: the easy work around is to print it then cut off the edges

Comment: or fool the printer by telling it that the paper is actually smaller then it is :)

Comment: I can't cut off the edges. The paper is pre-printed in colour to be name-tags for conferences.

Comment: Try fooling the printer, enter as paper size the actual and the margins it uses. So actual is 4.5 inches, you will enter 4.6 or 4.7 ? as paper size  and so on :) This way the printer will think the paper is large as it is and will print to the edges. You will have to try it out to find the right number.